# Extension of Tate's result regarding Tor

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

In a 1957 paper ([Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-1/issue-1/Homology-of-Noetherian-rings-and-local-rings/10.1215/ijm/1255378502.full)), Tate shows that if $I \subset R$ is an ideal of the noetherian ring R then there is a graded commutative DGA $X$ over $R$ with $H_i X=0$ except $H_0 X= R/I$ (I guess R should be noetherian). Further, $X$ is a free $R$ module in each degree. Is it known if there is a similar result for any other classes of commutative $R$ algebra?

If such an extension of the result is false, I would very much appreciate a counterexample.

Thanks for your time,
Sean

**EDIT:** (by other classes I mean commutative R algebras (Not DGAs) that are not of the form $R/I$). Also, I am happy with counter examples where the DGA is not level-wise free but instead projective or flat (although it shouldn't end up mattering for my purposes).

I am not concerned with relaxing the noetherian hypothesis but in resolving a different commutative $R$-algebra (not in the sense of Tate).

An extension of the above result would be equivalent to saying that there are no level wise free/projective/flat $E_\infty$ algebras with homology a given commutative $R$-algebra $A$ that are not strictly commutative (in the graded sense).

I worry that I am making things more confusing, sorry if that is the case, and thank you for the answers so far.

Comment: You don't impose conditions on $R$, so what do you meain by "other classes"?

Comment: I suspect the "commutative $R$ algebra" in the question refers not to $R$, but to the graded commutative DGA, which Tate calls an $R$-algebra.

Comment: @Fernando Muro: does that clarify things?
Thanks for the suggestions so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the protocol is on answering ones own question so I am making it community wiki.

What I was most curious about is the following:
When does the projective resolution of a commutative algebra as a module over a commutative ring have the structure of a graded commutative (skew in Tate's paper) DGA?

As Mariano pointed out, when I asked a different version on MSE, this is always the case.
Tate showed that this is true for algebras of the form $R/I$ where $I$ is an ideal of $R$ (the commutative ring we are working over). As Mariano points out, every finitely generated (I think this can probably be dropped) commutative $R$ algebra is a quotient of $R[x_1, x_2, ... x_n]$. So there is a graded commutative DGA that is a free resolution of $X$ as an $R[x_1, x_2, ... x_n]$-module by Tate's result. You simply forget from $R[x_1, x_2, ... x_n]$-modules to $R$-modules and you still have a graded commutative DGA that is a free resolution of $X$ as an $R$-module.

Anyway this is essentially what I was looking for.

(Mariano, if you want to post something like this, I will un-accept this answer and accept yours.)

Answer (score 2):

Alternative examples can be constructed using bar resolution and shuffle product:

Let $k$ be a commutative ring, $R$ a commutative $k$-algebra with augementation  $\epsilon: R \to k$ and let 
$B_\ast(R)$ be the bar resolution of $k$ over $R$. That is 
$$B_n(R) = R \otimes R^{\otimes n}$$ (tensor product is taken over $k$) with $R$-operation 
$$r \cdot (r_0 \otimes r_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes r_n) = (rr_0) \otimes r_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes r_n$$
and differential $d = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^id_i$ with 
$$d_i(r_0 \otimes \cdots \otimes r_n) = r_0 \otimes \cdots \otimes r_ir_{i+1} \otimes \cdots \otimes  r_n \hspace{6pt} (i < n)$$
$$d_n(r_0 \otimes \cdots \otimes r_n) = \epsilon(r_n) \cdot r_0 \otimes \cdots \otimes r_{n-1}$$

(see the book MacLane: Homology, X.2). Then $H_0(B_\ast(R))=k$, $H_i(B_\ast(R))=0$ $(i>0)$ holds and if $R$ is projective (resp. free) as $k$-module than $B_n(R)$ is a projective (resp. free) $R$-module. Eventually the shuffle product 
$$B_n(R) \times B_m(R) \to B_{n+m}(R)$$ 
turns $B_\ast(R)$ into a DGA over $R$ that is strictly (graded) commutative (see MacLane X.12.1, 12.3).

If $R = \mathbb{Z}G$ with an abelian group $G$, the example above gives just the usual construction of the Pontryagin product in group homology (see the book Brown: Cohomology of Groups, V.5).

Concerning the statement:

> An extension of the above result would be equivalent to saying that there are no level wise free/projective/flat $E_\infty$ algebras with homology a given commutative $R$-algebra $A$ that are not strictly commutative (in the graded sense).

I think there is a misconception: Projective/free resolutions are unique only up to homotopy. So, even if there is a resolution with strictly commutative DGA-structure there may also be other resolutions (of the same algebra) those DGA-structure is not strictly commutative. I think the best result possible is to show that (under suitable assumptions) each DGA is homotopy commutative.

Comment: Suppose I want to look at operations in the homology of a DGA coming from the $E_\infty$ structure. If the given DGA is htopy equivalent (quasi isomorphic) then all of the operations much vanish right? This follows from the comparison theorem that you cite above. I am interested in whether or not there are in fact non-zero operations.

Thanks for pointing out the Bar construction, I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

one result inspired by Tate's paper is

S. Lichtenbaum, On the vanishing of ${\rm Tor}$ in regular local rings. Illinois J. Math. 10 1966 220--226.

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that the OP is interested in relaxing the Noetherian condition on R, the article ["On the homology theory of general commutative rings"](http://www.ams.org.ezp1.lib.umn.edu/mathscinet-getitem?mr=169891) by Northcott (1961), may be helpful. The review states, in part:

> [...] [T]he author extends the machinery of Tate to study Tor$_R$(K,K) as an algebra, where K=R/M, M an (arbitrary proper) ideal of R. The main idea is to obtain algebraic resolutions of R/M and the results of Tate along these lines are extended to the non-noetherian case by transfinite methods.

Comment: The edit makes it clear that relaxing the Noetherian condition was not what the OP was looking for. I'll leave it up in case it is of interest to others.